# ReactJS - Updating a field onChange

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onchange, setstate

(warning: newbie question on React) I have the following TypeScript code:

```
// worldcup-app/src/components/world-cup.tsx

// Import deps
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import { WorldCupGameIF } from '../results/world-cup-game'

// Import styles
import '../../styles/worldcup.css'
import { Dropdown } from 'react-bootstrap'

export interface WorldCupScoreIF {
  games: WorldCupGameIF[]
  loading: boolean;
}

// Create Score component
export const WorldCupScoreEntry = (props: WorldCupScoreIF) => {
  // Prepare states
  let [game, setGame] = useState('')

  // Submit new book
  const handleGameSelect = React.useCallback((event: any) => {
    if ((event === undefined) || (String(event) === '')) return ''

    let game_name = ''
    let event_string = String(event).split('-')[1]
    props.games.forEach(game => {
      if (String(game.id) === event_string) {
        game_name = game._datetime + ' ' + game.host_name + ' - ' + game.visitor_name
        return
      }
    });
    console.log(game_name)
    setGame(game_name)
  }, [props.games])

  return (
    <div className="list-wrapper">
      {/* Form for creating new book */}
      <div className="list-form">
        <div className="form-wrapper">

          <div className="form-row">
            <input className="form-input" type="text" id="game" name="game" value={game} disabled />
          </div>

          <div className="form-row">
            <Dropdown onSelect={(event) => { handleGameSelect(event) }}>
              <Dropdown.Toggle variant="primary" id="dropdown-basic">
                Select Game
              </Dropdown.Toggle>

              <Dropdown.Menu>
                {
                  props.games.length > 0 ? (
                    props.games.map((game: WorldCupGameIF, idx) => (
                      <Dropdown.Item key={"idx_" + game.id} href={"#/action-" + game.id}>{game._datetime} <b>{game.host_name} - {game.visitor_name}</b></Dropdown.Item>
                    )
                    )
                  ) : (
                    <tr className="table-row">
                      <td className="table-item" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }} colSpan={8}>There are no results yet.</td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                }
              </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Dropdown>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am running into an issue where when a value is selected from the dropdown list first time around, the game name is populated in the input with the id "game".  However, the 2nd time the same game is selected, then the game name is properly reflected in the field.  The game data structure is as you would expect: id, _datetime, host_name, visitor_name + other fields that don't matter for this question.

After reading a whole bunch of Stackflow with similar questions, I thought I had to add:

```
  // Handle game selection
  useEffect(() => {
    setGame(handleGameSelect(undefined))
  }, [game, handleGameSelect])
```

but that wasn't it.

Comment: Would you please explain this more: `First time around, the game name is populated in the input with the id "game". However, the 2nd time the same game is selected, then the game name is properly reflected in the field.`?

Comment: When an option is selected from the Dropdown, the input field "game" stays blank.  However, if I select the same item, that input field is populated with the selected option (based on the logic in the callback).  If I select a different item, same happens: first time around the input field is cleared and empty, and the second time the other option is selected the input field is properly set.